# Sorting Columns by Header Value

Tags: r

I'm very new to R and currently trying to move away from my reliance on excel. I have a file which I'm trying to clean up and the final step of my clean-up procedure is to order the columns by the header value. The headers contain values for e.g.:

> "August.2019", "October.2019", "February.2020", "March 2020", "June
>   2019", July.2019, etc......."

I can't say exactly how many columns like this may exist, as this varies from file to file.

As you can see, they're not in any particular order. Is there a way to organise the columns in ascending order? Any guidance would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to convert the column names to Date and then `order`

```
df[order(as.Date(paste0("01.", names(df)), "%d.%B.%Y"))]
```

Adding a reproducible example,

```
df <- structure(list(August.2019 = c(1L, 5L), October.2019 = 2:3, 
      February.2020 = 3:2, March.2020 = c(4L, 1L), June.2019. = c(5L, 2L), 
      July.2019 = c(6L,1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

which looks like this

```
df
#  August.2019 October.2019 February.2020 March.2020 June.2019. July.2019
#1           1            2             3          4          5         6
#2           5            3             2          1          2         1

df[order(as.Date(paste0("01.", names(df)), "%d.%B.%Y"))]
#  June.2019. July.2019 August.2019 October.2019 February.2020 March.2020
#1          5         6           1            2             3          4
#2          2         1           5            3             2          1
```

We could use the same logic of converting columns to date using functions from other packages like `lubridate`/`anytime` or `as.yearmon` from `zoo`.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you for that. 
Just for learning purposes, if I'd wanted to order them in reverse order, descending rather than ascending order, is that a completely new problem, or just a re-structuring of the above?

Comment: @EhsanAsif yes, you can add `decreasing = TRUE` in `order`. `df[order(as.Date(paste0("01.", names(df)), "%d.%B.%Y"), decreasing = TRUE)]` Or reverse the regular order. `df[rev(order(as.Date(paste0("01.", names(df)), "%d.%B.%Y")))]`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `setcolorder` from `data.table`

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)
setcolorder(df, order(as.yearmon(names(df), "%b.%Y")))
df
#  June.2019. July.2019 August.2019 October.2019 February.2020 March.2020
#1          5         6           1            2             3          4
#2          2         1           5            3             2          1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(August.2019 = c(1L, 5L), October.2019 = 2:3, 
      February.2020 = 3:2, March.2020 = c(4L, 1L), June.2019. = c(5L, 2L), 
      July.2019 = c(6L,1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```